# Custom UIView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview

I can't work out if I am doing this with complete retardation or not.

I would like to add a custom view to my view controller in my storyboard.

I drag a view object on to the VC and set the class to my custom view class.

I would like to then have a xib file associated with this class so that I can design a user interface for this class separately from the storyboard.

The solutions which seem to be hacks referenced on stack overflow (adding the xib as a view in initwithCoder) have not worked for me, and the prospect of programatically aligning a load of images and labels when dragging and dropping would be so much easier really frustrates me.

Is there some easier method I'm missing, what is everybody else doing?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: You can either have a custom UIView with a xib that's added programmatically to the VC, or you can add elements to the view in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

With storyboard there is no xib file 
hack your items to .h 
press ctrl and drag a link to viewcontroller -at the bottom of ur viewcontroller in storyboard, or link it to your .h file and name it